# How to solve this recurrence T(n)=2T(n/5)+3T(n/10)+n

Tags: recurrence-relations

i need to solve the teta notation for $T(n)=2\cdot T(\frac{n}{5})+3\cdot T(\frac{n}{10})+n $
but the recursive calls each one multiplied by a different factor  make it not solvable with the master theorem , and I can't figure out how the recursive tree will look like.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thus, a very good occasion to forget the so called Master theorem and the recursive trees and to start *thinking*. First, if every $T(n)$ is noonegative, $T(n)\geqslant n$. Second, find some values of $c$ such that the property $T(n)\leqslant cn$ is hereditary (you should get that every $c\geqslant10/3$ works). Conclusion: for some fixed $c$ large enough, $n\leqslant T(n)\leqslant cn$ for every $n$, in particular, $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

We Show that a solution is $$T(n)=\frac{10n}{3}$$ then we have
$$2\cdot T(\frac{n}{3})=2\cdot \frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac{n}{5}=\frac{4}{3}n$$
$$3\cdot T(\frac{n}{10})=3\cdot \frac{10}{3}\cdot \frac{n}{10}=n$$
so we have $$\frac{4}{3}n+n+n=\frac{10n}{3}$$

Comment: how did you did conclude that T(n)=10n/3?

Comment: i have considered several examples, and a little bit intuition

Comment: And what if the initial conditions T(0) or T(1) do not fit this formula? Not an answer.